# Regular expression with hyphen in between numbers and fixed entire length

Tags: .net, regex

I want to validate expression that can only contain numbers split/or not split by dashes.
Also I want to validate that the entire string length is 6.
For the 1st part of task I made up something like this:

```
^([0-9]+-?)+([0-9]+)$
```

It gives me the proper result

> 123-12 valid
>
> 123456 valid
>
> 1-2-34 valid
>
> 1--2-3 not valid
>
> -2 not valid
>
> -2- not valid
>
> 2- not valid
>
> 123-abc-123 not valid
>
> a-123 not valid

But when it comes to limiting the entire string length to 6 like

```
(^([0-9]+-?)+([0-9]+)$){6}
```

it is not valid for anything.
Of course I could check the string length separately in code but I'd like to do it in regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the quantifier `{6}` to repeat a character class matching either 0-9 or - inside a positive lookahead to account for the number of allowed chars until the end of the string.

```
^(?=[0-9-]{6}$)[0-9]+(?:-[0-9]+)*$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=[0-9-]{6}$)` Assert 6 allowed chars till end of string
- `[0-9]+` Match 1+ digits 0-9
- `(?:-[0-9]+)*` Optionally repeat matching `-` and 1+ digits 0-9
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ap4Ii2/1)